# Let's break PolynumCrypt

Tags: mathematics, cipher

Introducing a *super secure* function to crypt your sensitive data - **PolynumCrypt**!

Say you wanted to crypt the string $\text{super}$, with a key of $6$.

- Get the ASCII values of the string, corresponding to $115,117,112,101,114$ in this case
- Turn that into a polynomial where the $n\text{th}$ coefficient corresponds to the $n\text{th}$ ASCII value, in this case $115x^4 + 117x^3 + 112x^2 + 101x + 114$
- Substitute the key value into $x$ to get your crypted number, in this case $179064$.

I've written a [Python script](https://ideone.com/8cDWzx) to make it easy to use.

Of course, brute-forcing $256^{n}$ possibilities for a string length $n$ is impossible, which makes this algorithm *super secure*.

***Maybe you can prove me wrong about PolynumCrypt, if you can crack my password:***

$\text{polynumcrypt(pass,1) = 1253}$
$\text{polynumcrypt(pass,1253) = 2102474472933529067195268690993346961762041}$

Comment: Is `pass` a variable or a string?

Comment: `pass` is a variable of type string.

Comment: it's a variable. `polynumcrypt("pass", 1) == 439`

Comment: By the way this is not an encryption but a hash. An encryption should have unique results and be reversible. this isn't the case.

Comment: A hash is fixed length. This isn't a hash. I also tried to use the word 'crypt' instead of encrypt because I realize it isn't reversible, but I'm all ears if you have a better word.

Comment: true. then it isn't either

Comment: @IvoBeckers Actually, if x > 255 then, this is quite reversible, is it not?

Comment: that's also true yes. So when $x > 255$ you can call it encryption

Comment: Assuming the key is unknown, however, this is actually a workable little sister encryption mechanism.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Technically if x > 127 should also work, as people rarely use the other ascii characters.

Comment: I guess it isn't *super secure* anymore...

Comment: @MarchHo Is it really? That would be interesting. For some reason I expect the unknown-key version to be easy to break too, but I can't think of a way.

Comment: @Lopsy: It's either easy to break or impossible to decrypt even for the person who has the base. Just iterate through all the possible bases and try and decompose the values therein.

Comment: @Joe Z. I'm picturing a version where you set the base as a random 1000 digit number. (Messages do get longer, but only by a constant factor.)

Comment: @Lopsy: In any case I think we can agree that it would be an extremely inefficient cipher.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We don't need to brute-force $256^n$ possibilities – since the overly large number is written in base $1253$ (that's what the polynomial is for) and ASCII characters are at most $128$, we can just express the large number in base $1253$ and extract the digits exactly as is.

Wolfram Alpha gives a decomposition of `112:48:108:121:110:111:109:49:64:108:115:46:83:69`. These ASCII values then evaluate to: `p0lynom1@ls.SE`

Comment: This is far more elegant than my answer. +1

Comment: I misread `@` as `A` when first solving this problem. This sort of password is hard to remember and easy to get wrong. Remember to always correct horse battery staple your passwords, kids!

Answer (score 8):

Is it?

> p0lynom1@ls.SE

How?

> Modulo the encrypted password by 1253 results in the last character. Divide it by 1253 and repeat and you get all characters.

Comment: Beat you to the punch by 10 seconds.

Comment: @JoeZ. But your initial answer was wrong. Too bad first edits don't show :D

Comment: It's not _my_ fault that `@` and `A` are right next to each other in the ASCII table! D:

Comment: :D Either way, good show! Should I delete this or something?

Comment: Nah, I already upvoted it. In any case your solution is slightly different from mine, and so is March Ho's.

Comment: March Ho doesn't need to reverse the characters in the end :D

Answer (score 5):

The first character of the string has the highest power, therefore it will dominate the polynomial.

Dividing the number by (1253^13) results in 112 (p)

The remainder of the division can be fed back into the calculation, finally resulting in the plaintext

> p0lynom1@ls.SE

The Mathematica code used to generate the answer:

```
string = "";
inNum = 2102474472933529067195268690993346961762041;
pow = 13;
While[pow >= 0, charfloat = N[inNum/(1253^pow)];
  charint = Floor[charfloat];
  string = string <> FromCharacterCode[charint];
  inNum = inNum - charint*(1253^pow);
  pow = pow - 1;];
string
```